# Inlining SVGs in HTML without using $.GET

Tags: jquery, html, http, svg, inline

I want to inline all svg graphics in html document. I'm using:

```
$('img[src$=".svg"]').each(function() {
    var $img=$(this);       
    var imgURL=$img.attr('src');
    $.get(imgURL, function(data) {
    ..............
```

Everything works fine when I requesting html document from http server. And of course when I double click on local html file(just opening locally with browser) this not work and get this error:

jquery.js:8630 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///file.svg. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Any ideas to fix this and to get SVG inline in HTML document with no need of HTTP server?

Answer (score 0):

your .svg files should be getting loaded without any extra work on your part. No code needed for what you are doing. See https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Yeah. I know this. This is just to get loaded svg graphics in <img src="image.svg"/>. This is OK. But next I need to make all svg IMGs to be inlined in html document?

Comment: That was also covered in the article I referenced. Basically just replace the <Img> tag with the whole contents of your svg file. If that's not what you are after then it's likely you need to amend your question to include the reason you are trying to do this

Comment: I want to automate inlining of svg in the html document because have many of them in external svg files. Also need to manipulate the path, circle, rect and all shapes in the svgs later with js

Comment: The article also covers some tools to embed the SVGs in your html files.